# Swing Timer and poor performance (Java, Swing)

Tags: java, swing

I have a problem regarding a **Swing Timer**. I'm trying to create a "sliding" animation for a **JPanel** that comes sliding in from the side when pressing a button. This actually works fine, but when I want it to slide out again, I am hit by extremely poor performance. Note: the JPanel is in a *JLayeredPane* and there are other components beneath it (it that matters at all).

Here is the code for slide in:

```
int boundsTo = GlobalValue.getLargeInformationBarWidth();
        final int[] boundsNow = {0};
        inSlideTimer = new Timer(1, ae -> {
            if (boundsTo > boundsNow[0]){
                boundsNow[0] = boundsNow[0] + 3;
                JourneyPlannerBarController.getInstance().getInformationBar().setBounds(0, 0, boundsNow[0], window.getFrame().getHeight());
                JourneyPlannerBarController.getInstance().getInformationBar().revalidate();
                JourneyPlannerBarController.getInstance().getInformationBar().repaint();
            } else {
                inSlideTimer.stop();
                inSlideTimer = null;
            }
        });
        inSlideTimer.start();
        JourneyPlannerBarController.getInstance().setupLargeJourneyPlannerBar();
}
```

and here is the code for the slide out:

```
int boundsTo = 0;
final int[] boundsNow = {GlobalValue.getLargeInformationBarWidth()};
inSlideTimer = new Timer(1, ae -> {
        if (boundsTo <= boundsNow[0]) {
            boundsNow[0] = boundsNow[0] - 3;
            JourneyPlannerBarController.getInstance().getInformationBar().setBounds(0, 0, boundsNow[0], window.getFrame().getHeight());
            JourneyPlannerBarController.getInstance().getInformationBar().revalidate();
            JourneyPlannerBarController.getInstance().getInformationBar().repaint();

        } else {
            inSlideTimer.stop();
            inSlideTimer = null;
            JourneyPlannerBarController.getInstance().clearJourneyPlannerBar();
            CanvasController.repaintCanvas();
        }
});
inSlideTimer.start();
}
```

As can be seen, the two chunks of code are almost identical, but the performance difference really is quite something. I have been trying to read up on SwingWorker, EDT and more, but I have so far not found anything that can help me.

Comment: Try increasing the delay to between 5-16

Comment: I'd also consider a "time" based solution, where the animation will run for a fixed period of time, it will generally produce an overall better solution

Comment: Thanks for the replies! 
I did already experiment with increasing the delay, and tbh, there doesn't seem to be any difference all the way up to 100. It's like the EDT is getting choked, but I have no idea why, since it's really just the opposite of the slide in, which works really well. 

In regards to the time based solution that you are suggesting, could you elaborate a bit further?

Comment: Remember, the timer is triggered within the EDT. Perhaps consider posting a runnable example

Comment: [mcve] is the thing we need to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You say the slide in and the slide out are the same procedures. For the UI they are not, and this by far.

When sliding the menu in, it is gettting wider at every iteration, so the UI needs to repeatedly repaint the menu. The underlying components get hidden bit by bit so nothing needs to be done there.

When sliding out, the menu is getting slimmer at every iteration, so the UI needs to repeatedly repaint the menu. But now that the underlying components are becoming visible, they also need a repaint. Depending on the time it takes to render the whole UI this is noticeable more work for the UI.

If you want to prevent that (or speed up), you could

- grab an image (like a screenshot) of the whole menu
- grab an image (like a screenshot) of the whole underlying UI

While sliding out, create a component that covers the whole window. For every iteration of the slide out, repeatedly draw the background image, then draw the menu image on top. This will be much faster, and once finished with the animation you remove this static image and allow the user to access the full UI again.